# Fix image height in Cargo Collective image gallery

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a Cargo Collective site for a friend and am somewhat perplexed by the CSS editor and its inability to fix the image height for all images in the gallery.

#### What I want

Image gallery changes its width to fit an image's full height, e.g. [this](https://ritaantonioo.cargo.site/Matilde-Rosa-Araujo) page will have the frog images as tall as the left image but not have the width cropped.

#### What I've done

This:

```css
.gallery_card_image {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Which does this:
[image: Image gallery with custom CSS]

Any tips go a long way

Answer (score 0):

this is just a personal opinion: try to set a max-height of 200px plus the 100% height.

`.gallery_card_image { max-height: 200px; height: 100%; }`

hope this works! :)